# how to use c++ signals on windows platform

Tags: c++, windows, signals

I know C on UNIX has `signal()` to call some function after some actions. I need it on Windows. I have found, what it exists [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). But I don't understand how to use it correctly.

I tried it like in UNIX:

```
signal(SIGINT, signalFunction);    //attach function to signal

void CRegBackupWiz::signalFunction(int sigNum)    //function
{
    m_Parent->SetWizard (swContinueFix);
}
```

I can't find, what is wrong with my code. Thanks for advices, I appreciate that.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @Dennis Error 1 error C3867: 'CRegBackupWiz::signalFunction': function call missing argument list; use '&CRegBackupWiz::signalFunction' to create a pointer to member c:\...\regbackupwiz.cpp 179

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so you need to look at how to use function pointers, and in particular how to use pointers to member functions : http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html.

In general if you are using a pointer to a function as a callback mechanism you should use a top level free function (non-member) as a wrapper. See here:
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/memfnptr-vs-fnptr.html

Answer (score 0):

That code doesn't actually work under Unix either.

Pointers to members are different from ordinary pointers - you need to use either a free function or a static member function.